# Rails, store multiple complicated relations into single hash record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash, record

Im studying rails associations.

suppose, i have a table which has massive associations.

```
Sample.rb

has_many :sample_assoas 
has_many :assoas through: :sample_assoa

has_many :sample_assobs
has_many :assobs through: :sample_assob

has_many :sample_assocs
has_many :assocs through: :sample_assoc

and so on...
```

in this case, i though due to complicated relations, the process will be very slow. (because rails should keep matching relations to get result.)

so i thought, what if i can store all the relational data to single hash to get faster result.

```
Samples schema 
id :integer 
name :string
hash :something...?
```

i found postgresql "hstore" stores data in a hash.

but is it good idea to store this way?

or do you have any suggestions?

thanks

Comment: i can't understand why i got negative feedback. if there has any problem, please let me know :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all a model can have any number or association. It won't affect processing time. hstore can not replace association, both are intended for different functionality.

Associations are used to simplify query building. Consider:

```
class ModelA < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :modelbs
end

class ModelB < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs :modela
end
```

You can find ModelB record associated with ModelA like below:

```
@modela = ModelA.find(xxx)
@modelbs = ModelB.where(modela_id: @modela.id)
```

Using association simply write:

```
@modela = ModelA.find(xxx)
@modelbs = @modela.modelbs
```

hstore are used to save value in hash format. so they are not intended to use as association. In most cases we don't want to save record in all associated table. So we should add association. If you use hstore in such case most of values will set to nil.

You need to manually iterate hash to get desired result in case of hstore.